# Is there a way to check if my monitor is switched on through a program?

Tags: windows-7, display

I need to know if my monitor is switched on, through a program so i can check when i am using a system through a remote session.

I've been playing around with chrome remote access, and a few other solutions for a while. One thing i realise is that if a monitor switches itself on, or mouse movement happens, and people aren't aware, they'll panic.

So counter intuitive as it is, is there a program that will tell me if one or all of the monitors on my system are switched on? Switching it *off* is trivial - there's tools for that, but knowing if the monitor is on seems like a useful thing as well

I'm running windows 7 systems for most part, so any solution would need to work on that, and ideally XP

Comment: By "on" do you mean switched on? Having power? Or displaying something?

Comment: Having power. The idea is that if i was to have the system with its monitor on power saving mode, moving the mouse would turn it on. Ideally i'd then realise it was on, and use something like nircmd to switch it off. I'd naturally be accessing the 'display' over rdp/chromeremote/some other remote access tool

Comment: Wouldn't an easier solution be to place a "privacy" viewer on the monitor? This would allow somebody to remove it if they had to sit at said computer but otherwise ignore if the monitor was on/off. Of course I would also just not even have a monitor for the computer.  What you want likely will be very hard to program, I am not aware of any way to poll a monitor, I just know Windows turns off the monitor by sending a special cpu signal.  This used to not exist.

Comment: Some monitors and video cards support EDID data (among other stuff, it gives you the supported video modes). If the video card does not return EDID data when the monitor is off, you could try using that to check if the monitor is on.